# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'w' of undefined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, resize

So I'm working on customizing my wordpress-based website and I was trying to make the website's layout fit and stay in place when the browser is being resized.

I am doing that by using jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){[Code to be executed on resize]});
```

Basically, as soon as I add that part to my file and I resize the browser this error turns up on chrome's console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'w' of undefined
>   jquery.ba-resize.min.js?ver=3.4.2:11

Now I am unsure what it means or what I might missing/forgetting/doing wrong but I am fairly sure this is what's causing malfunctions to my resizing scripts at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure you are not binding the event before jquery.ba-resize.min.js is loaded?

Comment: Quite frankly, no.. I'm not entirely sure. How would I go about checking that?

Comment: Scripts are loaded in order in which they are encountered in the page. So if you have the script tags in your HTML head element, you just have to make sure jquery.ba-resize.min.js is above your code. You should also have your code wrapped in a $(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: @mechanicalfish 

When checking the network tab in chrome, it looks like the theme.js file (where the resize code is located) is loaded at 140ms and the jquery.ba-resize.min.js is loaded at 180ms. That looks as though I am indeed trying to use it before it is actually loaded..

Is there a good way to delay my resizing function until after jquery.ba-resize.min.js is loaded?

Also, the error I mentioned in my question appears as soon as I start resizing the browser. Can the loading order still be the issue then? as I am not resizing it within those 180ms it takes for the file to load

Comment: I'm not familiar with the inner workings of this plugin but yes, it is probable that that's the issue. Change the order of your script tags and use [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @mechanicalfish Relocating the jQuery(window).resize section within my document ready function appears to have done the trick.

I was somehow not aware it was possible to do that within the document ready function.

Thanks a lot for your help! Much appreciated!

Comment: Great I'll write my comment as an answer so you can accept.

Comment: if you want to just attach a resize event to the window, you don't need to be using this plugin in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should binding the resize event after the document is ready to make sure the resize plugin  is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but just an observation:

window object has its own resize event, so there is no need to use that jquery plugin.

adding a resize event listener would have served:

```
window.addEventListener("resize",function(){[code here]});
```

Note: the plugin is for binding resize events to objects other than window object.

Worth checking:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/resize

**EDIT:**

```
                window.onload = function() {

    //this will block the horizontal scroll bar from appearing.
    document.body.style.overflowX = 'hidden';

    //the width will be adjusted at the initial page load. 
    document.getElementById("rsize").style.width = (window.innerWidth - 15);

    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        document.getElementById("rsize").style.width = (window.innerWidth - 15);
    });
};
```

Note: the end result depends on how you are implementing it, how the elements are styled.

i hope it helps.

Comment: hmm that's interesting. So Would using the eventlistener instead of what I've been doing now be a better solution in the sense that it would perhaps be faster (as it would avoid using the plugin)?

Comment: yes, for window resize it would be better and faster, as you won't be using jquery. pure javascript is always faster than jquery

Comment: [1 of 2] Thanks, I've been trying your solution and I must say it runs visibly smoother. It does seem to cause some issues as opposed to the other way of doing things.

What I'm trying to do is resize my site to whichever dimension without a horizontal scrollbar. Now in that, what seems to happen is that it first resizes the window. causing scrollbars to appear. then resizes the content accordingly which causes the scrollbars to disappear. however the jQuery(window).resize seems to also trigger when the scrollbars disappear, thus doing it all again and adjusting to that situation

Comment: [2 of 2]The eventlistener method does not appear to react to the scrollbars disappearance. Causing it to sometimes not display quite perfectly.The times it would not display perfectly are:
- At every initial page load
- At seemingly random times when resizing (Perhaps sometimes the code is processed quicker than other times, causing it to either finish before scrollbar disappearance or after?)

I'd like to try and make the eventlistener thing work reliably as its way smoother. Got any idea if the scrollbars could indeed be the issue? and if so, if there's a way I could solve that?

Comment: can you give the link so that i could have a look at it myself?

Comment: [1 of 2] Sure thing! I have left it at the eventlistener solution for you to check out, if you wish for me to change to the other solution, just give it a call. http://www.kevinsanders.nl

Now what might be handy to know is that I have set it up to follow several resizing steps (for mobile responsiveness, mainly) the one at 960px width or larger works fine. It's between 960 and 460px of width that the issues are present (for example when refreshing the page at that size, but also sometimes upon resizing).

Comment: [2 of 2] 

I think the slider resizing might have something to do with it all (as that resizement is present only between 960 and 460px) but it might also be coinsidence. The issue is that the min-height of the content area does not extend fully to the bottom, which is what I'm setting and calculating with jQuery/Javascript according to the footer, header and slider's heights.